# Return a function named temperature from a class and print it in a another file

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

```
class SensorData:

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):

        print("Connected!", str(rc))

        client.subscribe(mqtt_topic1)
        client.subscribe(mqtt_topic2)
        client.subscribe(mqtt_topic3)
        client.subscribe(mqtt_topic4)

    def on_message(self,userdata, msg):

        if msg.topic == "temp":
            self.temperature = str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
            return self.temperature
        print(self.temperature)
```

I want to return the temperature into another file and print this there.

```
from read import SensorData

data = SensorData()
sensor = data.on_message(self.temperature)
print(sensor)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onMessage()` function does not return anything and it is not called by any of your code.

The `onMessage()` function is only ever called by the MQTT client network thread when a new message is delivered from the broker.

You can use it to update a member variable on the instance of the `SensorData` class.

Comment: what do i have to do to make onMessage() return a value?

Comment: do you have an idea how i can fix this

Comment: aaj thats a pitty, i have to make connection and read out sensor data from an esp32 to a raspberry pi. and i though by this way i can store the info from the mqtt server